# Version ranges in gradle

Tags: gradle, dependencies, repository

What are the possible ways of specifying version ranges in gradle dependencies? I saw some 1.+ notation but I have not found a document which really says what is possible and what is not. Furthermore, I do not know whether the Maven ranges can be used as well.

Can somebody give me a short overview so that I can understand the rules?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The book "Gradle Dependency Management" states on p. 12 and 13 that, in addition to the +-notation (2.1.+ means the range from 2.1.0 inclusive to 2.2.0 exclusive) you can use the Ivy notation for open and closed intervals of the form

```
[1.0,2.0]
[1.0,2.0[
```

or also

```
[1.0, )
```

for "all versions starting from 1.0".

Comment: For info on what the Ivy syntax means in Gradle, consult: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/settings/version-matchers.html. For the case above, `]` at the end of the range means "inclusive" and `[` at the end of the range means "exclusive".

Answer (score 3):

### Preferred alternative

Specify the version range using Ivy notation. Here are some examples copied from [this web page](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781784392789/1/ch01lvl1sec10/using-dynamic-versions):

- `[1.0, 2.0]`: all versions >= 1.0 and <= 2.0
- `[1.0, 2.0[`: all versions >= 1.0 and < 2.0
- `[1.0, )`   : all versions >= 1.0       `// avoid. Unbound is dangerous!`

### Troublesome alternative

Use '+' in the major, minor or patch number. This approach has at least two issues:

- If you're building a lib and generating a pom file, the pom will be incompatible with maven, unless you apply some workaround to resolve the version and prevent the pom dependency to use '+' in the version element. See [this Gradle github issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1232).
- The meaning of '+' is prone to confusion. Well, maybe not, but ask around to see if all your peers know exactly the difference between `1.1.+` and `1.1+` in a gradle dependency.

### Ideal alternative

Avoid *dynamic* dependencies (using '+' or version ranges) altogether. Instead, use a fixed version dependency and update the version often with good testing. Here's why:

- **In the old days, backwards compatibility was sacred. That's not true anymore.** New versions often move/remove/rename classes and functions.
- If your dependency is dynamic (especially with '+' or unbound range), the next build may pick a new version that is incompatible with your project. The incompatibility may be detected only at rutime.
- Version X of your library as built today might be different from version X of your library built tomorrow if one its dependencies is dynamic and a new version is released overnight. This level of uncertainty is not desirable for libraries.

Comment: Bold statement. From my experience there are still plenty of people that care whether their code breaks and they still want the latest bug fixes without thinking about it. Semantic versioning is a well known convention that handles this situation and dynamic versions are great for that. I mean, what does a code version actually mean to your consumers if it breaks at any version?