# Gradle dependency versions '+'

Tags: maven, gradle

When we make Gradle dependency like,  1.2+ it will look for >= 1.20.
So i think it will look in maven-metadat "versions".
But if we just make + in our dependencies, where it will look?
In "versions" or in "versioning"-"latest"?
Can you help me with this question?

Comment: Usually, it is not a good idea to automatically pull the latest version because it makes builds not reproducible.

Comment: yeah, I also think so, dynamic versions are not safe, but in that case, I have no choice

Comment: Why do you have "no choice"? Please describe your situation.

Comment: this is an existing system and there is no way to change it in the near future

Comment: Yeah, but also in an existing project you can just use fixed version numbers and update them when needed.

Comment: of course, but in this situation i'm just wondering wheere gradle looks, when there is just +

Comment: The following does not answer your original question, but may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34810560/927493